# Force merge branch, ignoring overwritten files

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I have a git repository for an app I'm developing. I created a branch off master and now I want to merge it back into master. It refuses to do so because some files will be overridden, but these files aren't even supposed to be being tracked with version control.

How can I remove those files from version control, and force this merge to occur? I've committed the file a couple times but of course it keeps changing because it's a user interface state file. I've tried discarding changes then immediately attempting the merge, but I get the same error each time. The latest time, it's now mentioning an error about a working tree file and I'm not sure what that is, if I can overwrite it or not.

Essentially, I want the entire branch to overwrite master - there's nothing in master that isn't in this branch because I branched directly off of it then I never modified master.

```
The working copy "app name" failed to merge.

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
app name.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Administrator.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. 

error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
app name.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/app name.xccheckout 
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: Git won't stomp on uncommitted content in your worktree, tracked or not. Delete or move or commit the content. Look up [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)'s doc, it explains how to go back and excise what shouldn't have been tracked from your history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to delete your older `master` branch, and create a new branch named master from your `dev` branch.:

- `git checkout dev`
- `git branch -D master`
- `git checkout -b master`
- `git push -f origin master`

---

Coming back to the problem here:

> I've committed the file a couple times but of course it keeps changing
>   because it's a user interface state file

If these are files that can be regenerated from the code on the fly, then they need not be tracked in git. Remove them from `git` using `git rm --cached filename`, commit the removal/untracking using `git commit -m  "msg"` and put them in your gitignore using `echo filename >> .gitignore` on your dev branch.